# How to inject $httpParamSerializer for use in templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, ngroute

I am trying to inject `$httpParamSerializer` for use in `templateUrl` but I am having some issues.  There isn't any good documentation and examples of how to use `$httpParamSerializer`.

Example code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/data/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: function(params) {
             //NEED TO USE IT HERE
            }
        })
})
```

Things that didn't work, placing it like this:

`function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider,$httpParamSerializer ) {`

Also in the moduler, like this:

`angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', '$httpParamSerializer']).config(`

Any insight why this isn't working would help.

Comment: I created JS Fiddle to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/kh9oeq1y/15/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're in the config you need to get it from the provider itself. That is, inject the provider and call `$get`

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $httpParamSerializerProvider) {

    // get the serializer from the provider
    var paramSerializer = $httpParamSerializerProvider.$get();
    console.log(paramSerializer({a:1})); // test it

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: function(params) {
        // you can use paramSerializer(here
      }
  });
});
```

Working version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kh9oeq1y/16/

Answer (score -1):

[This forum](http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/1c33f70/unknown-provider-for-httpparamserializer.html) suggests it's a problem with your angular version. Check that you're using at least 1.4.0.

Comment: I am using 1.4.8.  Already checked the version.  Here is the JS Fidlle to play around with it, http://jsfiddle.net/kh9oeq1y/15/