# How to use httpparamserializer in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use httpparamserializer in Angular2. I googled a lot but the examples are only for angular1 as shown below.
[How to inject $httpParamSerializer for use in templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756603/how-to-inject-httpparamserializer-for-use-in-templateurl)

What would be the syntax to use it in Angular2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the exact same question [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39538440/2593877)

**My Solution**: I have a POST where I post data to a web service and I serialize my object this is how I do it. It is pretty simple and easy to use.

### [**URLSearchParams**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html)

Basic example

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('search', term); // the user's search value
```

[**Set Search Parameters**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#search-parameters)

**my-form-component.ts**

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions, Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';


// User is done editing, serialize and POST to web service
saveEdits(): void {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    // Dynamically serialize the entire object
    // *** THIS IS THE SERIALIZATION ***
    let params: URLSearchParams = this.serialize(this.selectedItem);


    this._http.post('http://URLtoPOSTobjTo/path', params, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

}

/**
 * Serializes the form element so it can be passed to the back end through the url.
 * The objects properties are the keys and the objects values are the values.
 * ex: { "a":1, "b":2, "c":3 } would look like ?a=1&b=2&c=3
 * @param  {SystemSetup} obj - The system setup to be url encoded
 * @returns URLSearchParams - The url encoded system setup
 */
serialize(obj: SystemSetup): URLSearchParams {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var element = obj[key];

            params.set(key, element);
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```

Comment: Worked great for me.

Comment: Super! I'm Glad to help out!

Comment: After reading some SO entries on this matter, this answer specifically was the one that helped me solve my issue. Certainly upvoted. Thanks!

Comment: Is the `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {` necessary?

Comment: Probably no, because its looping through the objects keys, but hey, it never hurts to catch a possible error just in case

Comment: How u will handle if there is a array inside param object? like this : param = {"obj" : [1,2,3,4,5]}

Answer (score 3):

### URLSearchParams `deprecated`

Please see the [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) as replacement for `URLSearchParams`

The usage is a bit tricky because the `HttpParams` is immutable so if you want to append many things one after another you will have to do it like this.

```
var params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('foo1', 'bar1');
params = params.append('foo2', 'bar2');
```